# How can I convert the values of dictionaries in one list to a new list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
    students = [
                     {'id': 123, 'name': 'x', 'g': 19},
                     {'id': 378, 'name': 'y', 'g': 8},
                     {'id': 934, 'name': 'z', 'g': 10}
                ]`
```

**I want this [19, 8, 10] of 'g' keys in all dictionaries and Comparison the number, and count many numbers in this list is smaller than 10 , I want to answer me (2)

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Do you want to get a list as a result (as the title of your question says)? Or just an integer?

Comment: I don't understand the question and the wanted result. Why are two numbers in the list `[19, 8, 10]` smaller than 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a generator:

```py
result = sum(1 for s in students if s['g'] <= 10)
```

This is compact way to write:

```py
result = 0
for s in students:
   if s['g'] <= 10:
      result = result + 1
```

Or if you're interested to get the list of `g` values:

```py
result = [s['g'] for s in students if s['g'] <= 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the list comprehension (e.g., here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to get the list of 'g' values:

Here is how I have done it. Creating a list for g_values and then counting how many are below ten:

```
# input data
students = [
     {'id': 123, 'name': 'x', 'g': 19},
    {'id': 378, 'name': 'y', 'g': 8},
    {'id': 934, 'name': 'z', 'g': 10}
]

# list of values (g)
g_values = [student['g'] for student in students]

# counting - how many below ten
sum([x<10 for x in g_values])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the dictionnary to a dataframe in case you need the list of several columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(students)
list_g = list(df['g'])
print(list_g)

print(sum(g < 10 for g in list_g)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).